# Configuring WordPress with Nginx on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wordpress

I am getting a 404 error with nginx when I got to localhost/WordPress. I have granted permissions to the var/www/html folder and nginx itself seems to be working fine. What could be the problem.

Comment: Is nginx running and pointing to var/www/html? Have you restarted nginx after making changes to the configuration? Are the wordpress files in var/www/html or in a subfolder?

Comment: This is probably better suited to [sf]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by pointing but I granted permissions. I restarted nginx and the files are in a wordpress subfolder in html

Comment: Your comment is noted miken32